# How to remove dom element?

Tags: javascript

Ok I've been so spoiled with Jquery that I don't even know how to remove an element anymore with plain Javascript.

So I have this  which I would like to remove with Javascript.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
function RemoveElement(elemID) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    if (elem.parentNode) {
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Node.removeChild` is the method, see documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild

Example:

```
  var parent = document.getElementById("mydiv");

  var child = document.getElementById("other");

  parent.removeChild(child);
```

Answer (score 2):

like:

```
container.removeChild(child);
```