# remove form element from document in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove dom element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020788/how-to-remove-dom-element)

How to remove form from document?

```
var formeEl=document.createElement("FORM");   
    formeEl.method="POST";
    formeEl.action="http://localhost:8080/url";
    document.body.appendChild(formeEl);
    formeEl.submit();
```

After submission form i want remove formeEl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
formeEl.parentNode.removeChild(formeEl);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
formeEl.parentNode.removeChild(formeEl);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.body.removeChild(formeEl);
```

Comment: +1 for encouragement. I'll presume you didn't see Alex's answer first.

Answer (score 1):

You attached it to `body` element, so just remove it from there.

```
document.body.removeChild(formEl);
```